# swfUpload stops after hiding its upload button

Tags: javascript, jquery, swfupload

I have `$('#just').hide()` SWFUpload's button's containing div, and the actual upload immediately stopped.

What is the reason for it? The debug said nothing.

Update: interestingly in IE7 it does not stop.

Comment: My guess is the Flash object gets destroyed for some reason. No idea why. You could try `.css("opacity", "0")` as a workaround

Comment: Modern browsers might halt Flash processing when the element is not visible, which makes a good deal of sense for most Flash purposes. You might try making the `<div>` "position: relative" and give it a "left" value of -10000 or something.

Comment: @Pekka that way the button does not disappear

Comment: Then try what @Pointy recommends, that sounds promising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. I needed to hide the button. I tried this (when the upload starts, i.e. bind this to uploadStart event:

```
$(".swfupload").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

That worked!